# How to convert "Mon May 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" date format to mm/dd/yyyy in angular7 and angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, date-pipe

How can i convert "Mon May 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)" to mm/dd/yyyy or any other format in angular 7. I'm using angular 7 and material design. Simple date pipe is not working.

"ReviewDate: new Date(2019, 4, 6)" is coming as "Mon May 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Comment: Have you tried with this ? `{{ yourDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}` ?

Comment: @Emilien thankyou.. i did it..